# Удвоить элементы массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удвоить элементы массива без использования циклов?

Comment: Ну можно использовать рекурсию.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Можно не писать их явно, воспользовавшись каким-либо перебирающим методом массива типа map / forEach / reduce итд, но внутри у них всех точно такой же цикл.

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4].map(el => el * 2));
```

UP: хотя если вы знаете длину массива, вы можете просто закодить эту операцию над каждым элементом, и никаких циклов не надо. вместо цикла копипаст и ручное увеличение инкремента

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr[0] = arr[0] * 2;
arr[1] = arr[1] * 2;
arr[2] = arr[2] * 2;
arr[3] = arr[3] * 2;
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: а если надо, чтоб выглядело вот так: [1, 3, 5]->[1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5]. Это не return или что-то типа такого?

Comment: @Matc это можно с помощью спред оператора -  `arr.push(...arr);`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.